# NodeJs Mocha Not Connecting to Database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to create some unit tests with `Mocha` and `Chai` but I am unable to connect to the mysql server. Here I have my unit test:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
let server = require('../app');
let should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);


describe('API endpoint /authenticate', function () {
  before((done) => {

    /* Todo: Clean up Database*/

    done()
  });


  it('should authenticate a user given CORRECT username/password', (done) => {

    let user = {
      username: 'ax850',
      password: 'test'
    };

    chai.request(server)
        .post('/api/authenticate')
        .send(user)
        .end((err, res) => {
          res.should.have.status(200);
          done();
        });

    done();
  });

});
```

As you can see, I am doing a `POST` request. Then in the script where I handle this `POST` request, I am connecting to a mySQL server like so:

```
 const db = require('./../../db_conn');
```

And in the `db_conn` I have:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const config = require('config.json')('./config.json');
let db;
const db_config = config.a_c.dbConfig;
function connectDatabase() {
  if (!db) {
    db = mysql.createConnection({
      host: db_config.host,
      user: db_config.user,
      port: db_config.port,
      database: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? db_config.db_test : db_config.db_dev,
      //database: db_config.db_dev,
      password: db_config.password
    });

    db.connect(function(err){
      if(!err) {
        console.log('Database is connected!');
      } else {
        console.log('Error connecting database!');
      }
    });
  }

  return db;
}

module.exports = connectDatabase();
```

However, when I run my `test` command: `mocha --timeout 10000`, it doesn't connect to the database. The `mysql.createConnection` runs unsuccessfully but doesn't give an error either. Any ideas? This works when I run the server without testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `done` before the request finishes.

```
   chai.request(server)
        .post('/api/authenticate')
        .send(user)
        .end((err, res) => {
          res.should.have.status(200);
          done();
        });
    // this is executed before chai.request is fulfilled
    done();
```